# ServiceStack - AutoQuery & Stored Procedure

Tags: servicestack

[Servicestack's Autoquery](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query) maps greatly to existing db Tables & Views.

Is there a way of mapping a class to a Stored Procedure, which can be read by AutoQuery?

```
[Alias("exec spStoredProcedureResult ??")]
public class StoredProcedureResult
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No AutoQuery doesn't support Stored Procedures which would be RDBMS-specific.

You would need to create a custom Service, which you can call in OrmLite with:

```
List<Poco> results = db.SqlList<Poco>(
    "EXEC spStoredProcedureResult @Id", new { request.Id });
```